# basic manipulation of sqlite tables

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables in my .sqlite.
These two tables are almost identical in terms of structure/content and I want one column of the first table to be replaced by one column of the second table.

This is what I have :

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48zGg.png)

I want:

- in Documents, `added` must become `oldadded` (to have a back up)
- then replace the whole column `added` of `Documents` by the whole column `added` of `doc3sept`.

So far, I have managed to select the `added` of `doc3sept` with
`SELECT added FROM doc3sept`, but I am stuck in replacing the old values of `added` of `Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to rename columns in SQLite - [see here.](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)

First add `oldadded` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Documents ADD COLUMN oldadded int
```

For updating column values from another table you cannot use `UPDATE` in SQLite. You can only use `INSERT OR REPLACE` command.

So next run:

```
REPLACE INTO Documents  (id, oldadded)
SELECT id, added FROM Documents
ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Then run:

```
REPLACE INTO Documents  (id, added)
SELECT id, added FROM doc3sept 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE doc3sept.id=Documents.id)
ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Be careful to have a backup before doing this if something fails.